BLTouch probing in mid air
I bought an Ender 3 v2 off a friend because he wanted to upgrade and I wanted to try getting into 3D printing (slightly relevant). He had a few upgrades on it, including a BLTouch.
I printed 2 prints successfully, but then it looked like the custom fan situation was dropping into the print layers and causing a lot of issues. I started taking it off, before I realized I'd need to probably 3D print a new fan solution (still slightly relevant).
After detaching the primary fan and BLTouch, I re-attached them.
My issue is that the BLTouch now probes in mid air without progressing down to the bed to probe the bed. I found similar issues on various posts, such as this one,
but the issues over there seemed to be new installation and issues with configuring it correctly.
This BLTouch was already working, I just detached it from the machine and reattached. I didn't touch any firmware or code anywhere.

Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Could you post a photo of the hotend with the custom fan solution? Also please check, did taking off the fan perhaps damage the wiring?

Please read BLTouch problem with pin deployment, this is a similar issue hinting to cable problems.

Thank you so much!!
That was it - a wire got pulled out.
